Is mathematics just "a part of physics", as stated by Arnold in 1997?
I've just finished reading "On teaching mathematics" by mathematician V. I. Arnold (b. 1937), it's the transcript of a talk from 1997 where he defended that mathematics is just a subset of physics (as I understood it). To me this seems utterly a wrong view, because, as Wikipedia puts it "In mathematics objects can be defined exactly and logically related, but the object need have no relationship to experimental measurements." (this seems very different from physics!) Are there any philosophers who agree with Arnold's view that "mathematics is a part of physics"? What are their reasoning to defend that view?
EDIT: It seems that in physics one can proceed by "finite induction" and generalize, while in mathematics one can even prove something is true for an infinite number of cases and it not be enough if it doesn't cover all cases. So the fields are very different.
2nd EDIT: There are valid criticisms about my question in the comments. I'll answer only one (sorry, lack of time in end of year!): I agree with Paul Tanenbaum's comment. Also, in my opinion, Arnold should be considered a philosopher of mathematics (because he discussed it so many times), not just a mathematician.
3rd EDIT: Judging by the many excellent answers (thanks to everyone who participated), the question "Is mathematics part of physics?" is a genuinely very difficult philosophical question that does not admit of simple "yes" or "no" answers, but ultimately depends on personal beliefs (and there are many possible answers!). I decided I would reward the answer that provided references to authorities who have thought seriously about this question for many, many years, and that serves as more "food for thought". In short: It seems to be an extremely difficult question, with many possible answers, and no certainty about this is obtainable (or so it seems).

Arnold's quip "mathematics is the part of physics where experiments are cheap" and associated controversy were discussed on hsm, How did Vladimir Arnold explain the difference in approaches between mathematicians and physicists? As you can see from links there, Arnold's views have few supporters, but there are some. Philosophical versions are more nuanced, including other sciences and not just physics, and getting more informative than "part". But Quine quipped that math faces "tribunal of experience" like sciences, and is only more "entrenched".

This question is similar to: Is mathematical truth empirical?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Arnold is known for his wry aphorisms which, like any good aphorism, convey some insight but are perhaps not to be taken too literally. I think his "mathematics is the part of physics..." quip is an example of this. Here is my favorite of his: "All mathematics is divided into three parts: cryptography (paid for by CIA, KGB and the like), hydrodynamics (supported by manufacturers of atomic submarines), celestial mechanics (financed by military and other institutions dealing with missiles, such as NASA)."

"Are there any philosophers who agree with Arnold's view that "mathematics is a part of physics"?" - do you want to hear only about philosophers who agree with such a radical view or also with those who disagree? Platonics would strongly disagree: for them mathematics studying ideal world is the only science and the other sciences are only shadows of mathematics.

I've read through the linked paper.  Twice to ensure I wasn't missing something.  Arnold only states that mathematics is a part of physics. Nowhere does Arnold state that mathematics is just a part of physics (as stated in the original post).  Those are two very different claims.  Also--despite the opening paragraph of the paper--most of the paper is arguing for the reverse. That physics needs to be part of mathematics, not the other way around. Even then, he's not saying that physics needs to be part of mathematics. He's saying hat physics needs to be part of mathematics education.

To some ears, your question, “Are there any philosophers who agree with Arnold's view that ‘mathematics is a part of physics’?” is roughly analogous to “Are there plumbers who think dairy farming is a part of Constitutional law?” Philosophy—even philosophy of math and philosophy of science—does not deserve any particular deference concerning math and physics over the views of actual mathematicians and physicists themselves.

@PaulTanenbaum, a hilarious comparison... :)  (and I do agree somewhat...)

@Paul Tanenbaum: I swear it was not my intention. English is not my native language, I don't intend to put philosophers above mathematicians (this would be totally unreasonable), I just wanted to know the status of his thesis in the philosofical community (as it seemed something not "main stream").

See A question of foundations

@ViktorK., well, PaulTanenbaum's funny response was also a substantial response, in my opinion. :)  Its silliness might be a distraction, yes, but, still, he's observing that these things are (or may be considered...) "incomparables". :)

It is clearly the other way around: Physics, like life, the universe, and everything, is a subset of mathematics.

You asked: Are there any philosophers who agree with Arnold's view that "mathematics is a part of physics"?  What are their reasoning to defend that view?
Roland Omnès stated mathematics is the laws governing the universe and its particles.
He called his view physism and it is remarkably popular given this survey though the population is quite small.
His reasoning:

If one reduced mathematics to the unique and modest role of a language of the laws of physics, the present state of theoretical physics and simple consistency requirements would not appreciably modify the present corpus of mathematics.

And

When a physical theory [..] requires mathematics in the formalized corpus [..], one can make the axioms necessary for the theory explicit, at least in principle, and follow the unfolding of ideas from these axioms into the mathematical corpus. [..] The physical laws, as we know them presently, reach through this process into an extremely large part of the mathematical corpus, and maybe all of it.

Another quote of Omnès:

There are basic axioms for logic and mathematics. These axioms are laws of physics. . . .

Roland Omnès was a French physicist but published some philosophical work as well. Besides, practically all French are philosophers..
There is also Max Tegmark who argues that physics is part of mathematics, in other words: mathematics is fundamental. Here he unfolds his Mathematical Universe Hypothesis or (MUH): Our external physical reality is a mathematical structure. Not exactly what you asked for, but an interesting read.

This answer is the most helpful for me (others might disagree). Since it provides an authoritative reference to the matter, I've chosen it as the "accepted answer", at least for now.

Mathematics is not just a part of physics.

In physics the concept of proof doesn't exist [1], only agreement with current observations (up to measurement errors). This is opposite of maths wherein countless observations and lack of counter-examples to a proposal don't matter - they may motivate one to search for a proof, but proved it must be to be accepted. A corollary is that once proven, a claim is considered true forever - a luxury no physicist expects or is comfortable with.

While maths may come from real, physical human minds, all that is needed for its existence is a set of abstract axioms. More minimal, the better. In fact, abstracting away the essence of reality into seemingly childish but powerful axioms is part of a mathematician's creative synthesis. One of the most famous example of this was the transition from physical geometry to Euclidean geometry to algebra. A person may sit locked in a room with a pen and paper and (in theory) rediscover all of mathematics thinking about the consequences of a few axioms. A physicist, on the other hand, also needs data to compare their musing's to. Without observations, the latter's theories are just those. If you (or your model) don't get physical, you aren't doing physics.

Another consequence of the dependence on axioms as 'the atoms of reality' is that by tweaking those assumptions, mathematicians can create entirely new, logically valid mathematical universes which have no physical analogs. In stark contrast, a physicist tweaks the assumptions of their model to fit the one and only universe they got.


The coupling between the disciplines helps - advanced mathematics aids scientists (not just physicists) in modelling nature with increasing accuracy, which presages advancements in experimentation, which in turn uncovers inexplicable phenomenon which prods researchers to discover new mathematical tools to explain those mysteries, which leads to better theories and so on - among other ways. But a coupling doesn't imply equivalence.
critique of @causative's viewpoint
I disagree with @causative's analysis that the mere act of thinking about mathematics or other disciplines makes them "physical experiments" of the brain. The further claim "that such experiments touch on absolute truth" carelessly twists the meaning of what an experiment is, even more (dare I say sullies it with the accursed phrase 'absolute truth'). The theorems of mathematics lie hidden in the axioms of the system they are proven under, like salt in sea. At the very least, they are implied by them if not eventually found inextricably linked. They (theorems) exist regardless of whether one proves them or not, thinks of them or not, discovers them or not. Their existence is predicate on that of their progenitor abstract axioms, which by definition are make belief (sensible, well motivated make belief, mind you) and need no physical existence. e.g. the line and point mentioned in Euclid's axioms of Euclidean geometry need not correspond to the physical, geometric notion of a line drawn or a point pinned - in fact they are atomic, undefined, non-absolute and fungible. As long as whatever one deigns to be a 'line' and a 'point' satisfy the axioms, then so will the 'geometry' generated by those 'line's and 'point's.
I won't comment on the unnecessity of a prospective prover of a theorem to (in theory) be intelligent, sentient or even alive.   Furthermore, thinking about a phenomenon doesn't impart to it the qualities of the thinker nor is it equivalent to an (actual) experimental validation of those thoughts.
To put everything into perspective, take the mathematical examples of everywhere negatively curved geometries or topologies which though existing comfortably without self intersections in higher dimensions, can't be embedded so in ours. Mathematicians think of them all the time, yet no process of physics can manifest them. This is contrary to what one expects from mathematical thought to ultimately be a 'physical experiment'.

[1]: To be clear, physicists do prove things all the time (in the mathematical sense), just not the validity or utility of those statements as the correct models of nature. That is always subject to experiments and is not self-evident or contained in theory. In contrast, in maths, the whole world can burn down for all it cares - its theorems still remain theorems. The annals of physics forever bask in the receding glow of the theoretical contributions (and in some cases discoveries) of giants that came before, even if critiqued upon by future observations.
(I had initially penned a longer clarification of this subtle difference in the reverence a physicist ascribes to the pedestal of truth that is forever occupied in eternal solitude by mathematics, but since it had begun to rival the length of the main body, I dropped it. This limiting brevity, like the original point being clarified, has brought upon the misfortune of, as @SethK puts it in the comments, being 'narrow to the point of silliness'. Alas, a major elucidation would fill a book.)

In physics the concept of proof doesn't exist, only agreement with current observations (up to measurement errors).
This is such a narrow view of physics as to be quite silly. Theoretical physics is by and large devoted to proving things within certain physical theories. If those theories aren't precisely realized in nature, that doesn't make the study not physics. E.g. the discoveries of asymptotic freedom or spontaneous symmetry breaking in quantum field theories would still be physics even if those particular phenomena weren't realized in the Standard Model.

And often one is proving statements about idealized systems. Consider for example Schwarzschild's derivation of spherically-symmetric, vacuum solutions to Einstein's Equations certainly counts as physics. Will we ever literally discover a literal Schwarzschild black hole? One that doesn't have an accretion disk or any angular momentum or any CMB photons around it? Absolutely not. Regardless, Schwarzschild was doing physics when he proved the existence of these idealized solutions to General Relativity.

Of what you say about my viewpoint, ask yourself whether it might also apply to experiments in physics. Can experiments in physics touch on absolute truths, which are true regardless of whether anyone performs the experiment? Can the facts of physics lie hidden within the behavior of a system, like salt in the sea? Yes, and yes. Consider Ramsey's theorem. It says something about whether you can physically construct and color K6 - with say 2 colors of lug nuts connected by strings - without a clique of 3 lug nuts of the same color. You can't. That's a physical fact.

(And note that this physical fact is true regardless of whether you actually do try to construct such an object from lug nuts and string.) All mathematical theorems correspond to physical facts like that. They aren't all as nice as lug nuts connected by string, but at the very least, they say something about what can be proved. And a proof on paper or in the voltages of computer memory - or in neurons of your brain, for that matter - is a physical object, as much as an arrangement of lug nuts and string is a physical object.

This is closely related to intuitionism, according to which mathematics is the study of what objects can be mentally constructed. But of course to mentally construct an object - to imagine a triangle, for instance, or indeed a non-Euclidean geometry or a Schwartzchild black hole - is to form a pattern of neuron activations, which is physical.

@SethK Agreed (and clarified (briefly) in the answer). Unequivocally, Einstein, Schwarzschild (and Newton, Gibbs, Witten, Madecena ...) were and are (extra-ordinary) physicists.

Arnold explains what he means, beginning with:

The scheme of construction of a mathematical theory is exactly the same as that in any other natural science. First we consider some objects and make some observations in special cases. Then we try and find the limits of application of our observations, look for counter-examples which would prevent unjustified extension of our observations onto a too wide range of events (example: the number of partitions of consecutive odd numbers 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 into an odd number of natural summands gives the sequence 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, but then comes 29).
As a result we formulate the empirical discovery that we made (for example, the Fermat conjecture or Poincaré conjecture) as clearly as possible. After this there comes the difficult period of checking as to how reliable are the conclusions .

He goes on to describe his view that axioms should be understood as hypotheses (about the objects mentioned above), the same as scientific hypotheses, rather than as absolute truths.

Certainly, computer experimentation is common in mathematics. And certainly, this experimentation is an actual experiment, no different from an experiment in physics; we are setting up initial conditions for a physical system (the inputs to the computer) and observing the physical outcome (what the computer displays on the screen).
In addition to computers, mathematicians also use their brains. But is the use of the human brain any different, in principle, from use of the computer? If we suppose the brain is simply a physical system like any other - like the computer - then for a mathematician to ask themselves what they think about a (mathematical) topic is little different from asking the computer what it calculates based on an input. They are both physical experiments.
One might object that such experiments touch on absolute truth, and thereby wish to distinguish them from experiments in physics. But we must still remember that nothing is happening within the computer or the brain but physics. That's what we must reconcile; we can't draw a line separating mathematics as relating to the absolute and physics as relating to the real world, because it's all physics. So the question to think about is how can physics touch on absolute truth? We've established it must, somehow; what's the process?

Thank you! The last paragraph reminds me of the "Turing-Wittgenstein debate" where Wittgenstein made analogies with mental calculations and counting.

Mathematical "experiments" are nothing like physical experiments. Mathematical "experiments" are just automated mathematical reasoning. They reveal nothing that you couldn't have in principle discovered just by doing math. Physical experiments reveal things that could only be revealed by doing the experiment.

@DavidGudeman: Actually, these days there is such a thing as experimental mathematics, where one uses a computer to throw a huge number of test cases at a theorem. It is used when attempts to prove or disprove the theorem rigorously have failed, as a way of attempting to find a low effort disproof before investing years of effort hunting for a proof (and possibly failing). Obviously, failing to find a counter example does not constitute a proof, but it may increase confidence. There is also Monte Carlo simulation; one of my first programming homework assignments was approximating pi that way.

@keshlam, in other words, it does a quick search for something you could in principle have done by hand without doing an experiment. Like I said.

@DavidGudeman: Dozen of one, six and a half of the other. You can do an intensive enough search to give you some statistical confidence, when doing an equivalent search would itself take you years. Whether you call that an experiment or not is up to you. However, it's a side issue in any case, not addressing the question that was posed.

@DavidGudeman - At some point the words "in principle" may start to sound hollow. Also, "in practice" may in practice be more important than "in principle". I'm tempted to think it's even more important in principle :)

@mudskipper, in this case "in principle" is the essential point in distinguish the empirical from the a priori. Once again: there is no way you can know the results of a physics experiment without experimenting, but you can know the results of a mathematical problem without experimenting. That's an essential difference.

@DavidGudeman To know the results of a mathematical problem you must do an experiment, either asking a computer to calculate something or asking a brain to calculate it, both experiments in which you set up initial conditions for some physical system and observe the result. If you believe the brain works on physics, same as the computer does, then there is no line to draw between these two types of experiments.

@causative, you are changing the word experiment to mean something it doesn't mean.

@DavidGudeman I am taking it to mean, that you set up some initial conditions for a physical system, and then observe the result.

@causative solving a mathematical problem or proving a theorem isn't setting up a physical system and then observing the result. First, there are correct and incorrect results. That's not true with experiments. Second, even if you assume there is some sort of calculating device (an unmotivated assumption), the actual device is irrelevant. Any device which achieves the correct result is equivalent. There is no physical experiment where it doesn't matter if you are observing electrical, mechanical, or hydraulic actions. In physical experiments, the materials matter.

@DavidGudeman Neither of your points challenges the fact that running a computer calculation involves setting up initial conditions for a physical system (the computer) and observing the result (on the screen). Rather, your points just describe some unusual characteristics of computer experiments. Many kinds of experiment may have unusual characteristics. And your points are not absolute demarcations; there are times where we might say that an experiment in physics gave an incorrect result, such as by instrument error, and when we may experiment with e.g. water waves to model light waves.

@causative, I give up. The difference is obvious and critical, but if you refuse to see it, you refuse to see it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Whether you like the term and concept or not, it is used. See, eg, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_mathematics

I would say that mathematics is a tool.
Using a hammer is part of woodworking, but it is also part of metalworking, driving railroad spikes, breaking rocks, ringing bells, and many other tasks large and small.
Similarly, using mathematics is part of physics, but also part of economics, statistics, and so on. Physics has been a strong driving case on mathematics, but has no exclusive claim to it nor is it the only driver.
Conclusion: no.

Roger Penrose (Road to Reality) has a nice diagram showing the Platonic mathematical world, which contains the Physical world (the reverse of Arnold!), which contains the Mental world, which contains the Platonic mathematical world, which contains...

There is a profound similarity between the various activities that humans carry out: They are all carried out by a human and humans are most often very like each other.
Thus, buying a sandwich and working out a theoretic model of fundamental particles both involve the same basic activities, each of which is related to our perception organs as well as other organs in our body, such as our hands and our feet. In both cases, we use our eyes to observe the material world, we use our mind to figure out what to do next etc. The body of a physicist is really not much different from the body of a policeman, or the body of a priest.
Science should be seen as mere systematisation of what we all do everyday of our lives. Mathematics itself is just one of those things that humans do. We can choose to emphasise the differences or the similarities.

Mathematics isn't a part of physics, but physics is a part of mathematics.
Consider this: mathematical proofs only care about the result. Whether the proof is justified true belief in the sense of knowledge (a process type of thinking) is irrelevant. Case in point: Andrew Wiles's proof of FLT is a whole bunch of disjoint facts that by accident happen to arrive at the conclusion that x^n + y^n fails to equal z^n for all n ≥ 3 where x, y, z are arbitrary integers. From the philosopher's perspective, this is a Gettier type of knowledge, where it is justified true belief that is, in some sense, true by accident. Not unlike the story of Christopher Columbus discovering the New World by studying some ANCIENT GRΣΣK text purpoting that the proportion of the circumference of the world is 1/8th that of Europe (or something along those lines). This, by the way, isn't true for the proof of the four color theorem, because the algorithm used by the mathematicians is provably correct.
